# How to get extra data in getList()?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have controller:

```
class MyController extends AbstractRestfulController{

    protected $myTable;

    public function getList(){
        $results = $this->getMyTable()->fetchAll();
        $data = array();
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $data[] = $result;
        }
        return new JsonModel(array(
            'data' => $data
        ));
    }

[...]
```

and I check:

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost/myapp/restroute -X GET
```

and it's fine. But I want to send to this method extra data, for example:

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost/myapp/restroute -X GET -d "name=john"
```

How to read this data in getList() method?

I could use create($data) method but somehow it does not fit me (create method is for creation, etc). I want, for example get list of some type of objects limited by variable in $_GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `AbstractRestfulController`, there's a helper method called `processBodyContent` which is ideal for what you're trying to do:

```php
public function getList()
{
    $content = $this->processBodyContent($this->getRequest());
    $name = array_key_exists('name', $content) ? $content['name'] : '';

    // ...
}
```

As you're using GET thought, you should consider doing:

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost/myapp/restroute?name=john -X GET
```

You can then retrieve within `getList()` like this:

```php
public function getList()
{
    $name = $this->params()->fromQuery('name');

    // ...
}
```